# Y-axis doesn't fit the number of timelines

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have a plot made with `px.timeline` with a lot of input data and I see that numbers in rows on Y-axis are different from the number of bars. It seems like plotly didn't scale Y-axis to fit a number of time bars, but I didn't find any parameters to change it.

This is an example of how it looks:

[image]

But if I will zoom in to the smaller region with fewer amounts of bars the Y-axis starts to fit:

[image]

Are there any ways to make the plot kinda "scrollable" or re-calculate font size to align the Y-axis with a number of timelines?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- from image it appears that **yaxis** is categorical.  Have simulated data to replicate
- you can effectively control **yaxis** through **range**.  Have built a drop down menu that will allow user to select section of **yaxis**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Task": [f"{a}_{b}" for a in range(8) for b in range(15)]}).assign(
    Start=lambda d: pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-jan-2010", periods=len(d) * 10))
    .sample(len(d))
    .values,
    Finish=lambda d: d["Start"] + pd.Timedelta(days=25),
)

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task")

BARS = 15
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": f"{fig.data[0].y[s]} to {fig.data[0].y[min(s+BARS, len(fig.data[0].y)-1)]}",
                    "method": "relayout",
                    "args": [{"yaxis": {"range": [s, s + BARS]}}],
                }
                for s in range(0, len(fig.data[0].y), BARS)
            ],
            "active": -1,
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the answer. It's not exactly what I wanted, because I still have a plot, where Y-axis is not matching bars, but I see how your code snippet can help me a bit by zooming closely to selected rows from updatemenus. One more note, that I do have not an exactly categorical Y axis, because colors are made from another column of my DataFrame.